# Profiling C program in XCode

Tags: c, xcode, xcode4, profiling, profiler

I'm using XCode to develop a C command line utility and I'm attempting to using XCode's profiling capabilities to track program allocations and possibly memory leaks. I can attach an allocation tracker utility just fine to the program itself and it works, the problem is I cannot interact with the program from this point and it's just stuck in its initialized and waiting state (the program is definitely running in the background somewhere I just cannot get to it). I've tried tweaking various settings to no avail, any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you launch Instruments outside of Xcode, you should be able to use the pull-down list above 'Target' and 'Attach to Process' to profile any already-running program. So one option — given that the way you describe your program makes it sound interactive — is to launch your utility in a terminal then to attach Instruments to it.

E.g. `vi` isn't symbolicated but running Instruments against it has just revealed that when in insert mode, it spends about 14% of its time in `write` and 4.5% in `strcmp` (albeit that with something like vi the processing is so minuscule that there's bound to be sampling error in there).

Comment: I was able to get the instruments up separately and attach it to my command line utility but the allocation tracker tool is informing me that "Attaching requires that the target utilize CoreFoundation.framework". I tried adding the framework to the program in XCode but it had no effect.

Comment: Per https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingPatterns.html "The information displayed by the ObjectAlloc instrument is recorded by an allocation statistics facility built into the Core Foundation framework." so if you're not actually using Core Foundation it doesn't seem to have anything to latch onto. The memory monitor will work but gives little information over `top`; maybe you can get some mileage from the command-line `leaks` tool (as per http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/leaks/ )?